# grails executor plugin - executorService injection

Tags: spring, grails, code-injection, executor

Trying to use the executorService injection in my service but it fails. When I read the document for the plugin, it mentions that the executorService is injected through the conf/spring/resources.groovy file. But my resources.groovy file is empty (actually an empty bean definition) and am not sure if I need to put something in there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What does your service look like?  Do you have this at the top of your service:

```
def executorService
```

??

If so, I'd also confirm that you've got the plugin installed.  It shouldn't actually mess with your resources.groovy file directly, it does the spring injection stuff in the plugin itself.

Another thing you could do would be to spit out all of the configured beans in your system (either in the console, if you've got the console plugin installed, or by putting this in your BootStrap.groovy file and logging the answer out:

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.beanDefinitionNames.sort().each {
 println it
}
```

If you put it in BootStrap.groovy, you'll also need to put `def grailsApplication` at the top of the BootStrap class so that the grailsApplication object gets injected.